# Como retirar um certo elemento na hora de fazer o site responsivo?

Tags: html, css, elementos

gente eu sei que parece uma pergunta besta mas é o seguinte eu estou fazendo um site responsivo e claro que o que eu fiz para web não ira se encaixar em um celular.

entao supondo que eu fiz para web uma tabela com 9 partes, em um celular eu gostaria apenas de deixar 4 ou 5, como retirar o restante dos elementos sem interferir no html do site web?  pois é obvio que mesmo que eu faça as reduções no css uma tabela de 9 partes ficaria ridicula e pequena demais.

espero que tenham entendido,

---

então a parte das tabelas ate consegui arrumar pra colocar uma embaixo da outra, mas ainda não sei como retiro elementos tipo uma foto.

no html vai estar la 
no css eu posso editar img {... tal }

mas  pra retirar? tipo eu não quero mais esta imagem aparecendo na parte responsiva como faço? pq um none não tem como dar. e como retiro sem alterar o html e o css da parte web

---

e tambem pq tem muitos itens que não quero que apareçam no responsivo senão ficara grande demais

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara... Vc já tem o código da versão desktop de 9 partes pelo menos? Tem alguma imagem de como deve ficar o layout no desktop ou no mobile? Só com esse relato não da para te ajudar muito...

Comment: Não está dando para entender o que você chama de "partes" da tabela. São colunas? Linhas? Blocos? Favor [edit] a pergunta acrescentando mais informações. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar media queries para fazer isso. Seria algo assim:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
//Ocultar colunas
}
```

Existem duas alternativas, uma é a que você falou na pergunta, que seria esconder colunas. Aqui tem um tutorial passo a passo:

https://phppot.com/css/automatic-column-hiding-using-css-in-responsive-table/

A outra seria inverter a tabela, ou seja, transformar as colunas em linhas. Aqui tem um exemplo:

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/